# Always display submenu

Tags: html, css

I want to always display its submenu as well. There must always be an active main menu item so that its sub menu can be shown in sub-menu part. How can I customize following code according to my specifications:

```css
p,
ul,
li,
div,
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}
#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
}
#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">

  <ul class="parent-menu">

    <li><a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Books</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">item</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Support</a>

      <ul>

        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">T&C</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>

  </ul>

</nav>
```

Comment: Your specifications are not clear.

Comment: As when we hover main menu item, it displays its sub menu. But I want that sub menu of 1 item must always be displayed. And when I click on other main menu item, it will display its corresponding sub menu. Got it?

Comment: You need to use either server side script for that, or hardcode it.

Comment: How can I do this hardcode thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Add a `.active` class that is same as `:hover`.
2. Add the `class="active"` to whichever `<li>` you wanna keep it displayed.

**Books are Always Active**

```css
p,
ul,
li,
div,
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}
#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li.active a,
#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}
#menu ul li.active > ul,
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
}
#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul class="parent-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Books</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Here cars are always active**

```css
p,
ul,
li,
div,
nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Calibri;
}
#menu {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.parent-menu {
  background-color: #0c8fff;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menu ul li.active a,
#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #007ee9;
}
#menu ul li.active > ul,
#menu ul li:hover > ul {
  left: 200px;
}
#menu ul li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu ul li > ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul class="parent-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home & Kitchen</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Clothing</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Cars & Motorbikes</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Books</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deliveries</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">T&C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```